# Карты в Python Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всех приветствую!

Делаю карту. Использую Python и библиотеку Folium. Может кто сталкивался с таким вопросом: есть ли возможность использовать карты в режиме оффлайн?

Может какую библиотеку подключить для этого нужно?
Или скачать карты с ресурса и использовать: **если да** - то какой ресурс подойдет?
Совместим ли он с библиотекой Folium?

Comment: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/351#issuecomment-348689317 ,https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425593/12785139

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!